# Tool to combine Messenger's chatting logs?

Tags: windows-live-messenger

Is there any tools can combine messenger chatting logs (HTML format) into one file? ie. foo@gmail.com.HTML, foo@gmail.com (2).HTML, foo@gmail.com (3). HTML into foo@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a script for msn plus called -- [Log Manager](http://www.msghelp.net/showthread.php?tid=77116) resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since MSN Chat logs are in XML format, here is a way to merge these file into a single one:

http://www.codeplex.com/MsnHistoryMerger

Comment: Thanks for the awesome tool.But I just found my log format is html due to chat was logged by msnplus not messenger itself. Is there any tools to merge msnplus logs? Thank a lot!